# Category menu for tx_news that adds a category to the existing list view instead of replacing it

Tags: typo3, tx-news

I have a list view, showing news of a specific category A.

I want to further limit the list by one additional category the user can select.

I add a category menu to the page. The list view page is the same as the initial list view page.

After the user chooses a category B from the category menu, the page displays the news items with category B.

Instead of this, I want the news items that are of the initial category A **and** the user selected category B.

How would I do that?

Comment: I ended up overriding the category template and hardcoding there the generated links. The line `additionalParams="{tx_news_pi1:{overwriteDemand:{categories: category.item.uid}}}` became `additionalParams="{tx_news_pi1:{overwriteDemand:{categories: '{category.item.uid},XXXXX'}}}` where XXXXX is my additional category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build a link holding both category IDs. Currently it is not implemented that you can provide an **additional** category.